# Node express change static folder on a user by user basis

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

Is it possible to do something like this with node and express middleware?

```
app.use('/',express.static('public'))

app.get('/public', function() {
  app.use('/',express.static('public'))
})
app.get('/public2', function() {
  app.use('/',express.static('public2'))
})
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is allowing users to have their own "public" directories to serve static files. the directory structure would be something like /user/< hash >

Comment: you can create a folder based on user name or id whichever is unique, and based on that value call `express.static()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I have a solution for you!

```
app.get('/:user', function(req, res, next) {
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/' + req.params.user)));
    res.send('');
});
```

To explain, imagine the two files at the paths:

`/__dirname/public/user1/userdata.text`

`/__dirname/public/user2/userdata.text`

By visiting the following two URLs:

`http://localhost:3000/user1/userdata.txt`

`http://localhost:3000/user2/userdata.txt`

You'd be requesting those two different files respectively. If the file doesn't exist, it throws a `404` like you'd expect!

Hope this helps.

Comment: @squirreldev Make sure it is, and then remember to accept the answer :)